# How to map an array

Tags: mule, dataweave

Input:

```
{
 "count": 3,
 "employees":
    [
      {
        "name":"appy",
        "age":34
      },
       {
        "name":"happy",
        "age":38
      },
      {
        "name":"cruise",
        "age":36
      }
       
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
      {
        "first":"appy",
        "age":34
      },
       {
        "first":"happy",
        "age":38
      },
      {
        "first":"cruise",
        "age":36
      }
       
    ]
```

This is my input i am trying to add "first" in "name" how can i do any suggestions i am using Map function here.

"first" in "name" place i am trying to use map function

Answer (score 1):

Just map the elements:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.employees map {
    first: $.name,
    age: $.age
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "first": "appy",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "first": "happy",
    "age": 38
  },
  {
    "first": "cruise",
    "age": 36
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please try to be specific. If you have an issue or error describe it, add error messages, etc. I tested the script myself in DataWeave playground (https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/) before posting so I know it works.